# SQL Query output columns name

Tags: sql

The below query return the correct results, but I am confused and unable to get the desired columns in output. The query returns the columns `ID`, but I dont knw how to fetch same column `name`.

```
SELECT stock.Stock_Code, route.EndItemStockID, routeD.InFeedStockID
FROM tbl_Bom_Route route
INNER JOIN  tbl_Stock_List stock
ON route.EndItemStockID = stock.Stock_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Machines mac
ON route.MachineID = mac.MachineID
INNER JOIN tbl_Bom_Route_Detail routeD
ON routeD.BOMRouteID = route.BOMRouteID
INNER JOIN tbl_Bom_Route_Metadata routeM
ON routeM.BomRouteID = route.BOMRouteID
```

The attached image also shows the output as well as the expected results with desired columns. Optimization will be appreciated if require.

[image]

Comment: This is year 2023.  Please use proper `JOIN`.

Comment: I updated the query, I am interested in results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If EndItemStockID and InFeedStockID both refer to the Stock_ID in tbl_Stock_List, and you want to fetch the corresponding Stock_Code for both of them, you'll need to join the tbl_Stock_List table twice, once for each ID. Here's how you can do that:

```
SELECT 
  stock1.Stock_Code AS EndItemStockCode,
  stock2.Stock_Code AS InFeedStockCode
FROM tbl_Bom_Route route
INNER JOIN tbl_Stock_List stock1 ON route.EndItemStockID = stock1.Stock_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Stock_List stock2 ON routeD.InFeedStockID = stock2.Stock_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Machines mac ON route.MachineID = mac.MachineID
INNER JOIN tbl_Bom_Route_Detail routeD ON routeD.BOMRouteID = route.BOMRouteID
INNER JOIN tbl_Bom_Route_Metadata routeM ON routeM.BomRouteID = route.BOMRouteID;
```

By joining the tbl_Stock_List table twice (with aliases `stock1` and `stock2`), you can fetch different Stock_Code values corresponding to `EndItemStockID` and `InFeedStockID`. This allows you to work with two different values from the same column in the output, using different aliases (`EndItemStockCode` and `InFeedStockCode`) to distinguish between them.

Comment: I can fetch more columns if I need too, the issue is `EndItemStockID` and `InFeedStockID` are both referring to one column but different values & I don't know how can I fetch different values in 'SELECT' clause of same column with different alias.

Comment: `EndItemStockID` and `InFeedStockID` are part of `tbl_Stock_List` which has their `Stock_Code`. I need to fetch `Stock_Code` of both above columns, not their ID's.

Comment: Check last answer update.

Comment: It ends with error `The multi-part identifier "routeD.InFeedStockID" could not be bound`

Comment: I am marking this as answer because eventually after some tweaks I found a solution. Your give me the solution of getting same column with different aliases which I was looking for & problem is being sorted out. Thank You 